# 13349 Oracle error geometry -- polygon intersects itself

Tags: oracle, oracle-spatial

I have a table in Oracle which holds data for a polygon layer. I validated it

```
--validate layer
CREATE TABLE Geom_Valid_Neighbour (SDO_ROWID ROWID, STATUS VARCHAR2(2000) );   
EXECUTE MDSYS.SDO_GEOM.VALIDATE_LAYER_WITH_CONTEXT ('OTTAWANEIGHBOUR', 'GEOMETRY', 'Geom_Valid_Neighbour'); 
SELECT * FROM Geom_Valid_Neighbour;
```

and got the following errors:

```
+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|     SDO_ROWID        |                STATUS                                    |  
+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|         (null)       |  Rows Processed <50>                                     |   
| AAA2EHAANAAB76nAAA   |  13349 [Element <1>] [Ring <1>][Edge <112>][Edge <109>]  |   
| AAA2EHAANAAB76rAAC   |  13349 [Element <1>] [Ring <1>][Edge <51>][Edge <55>]    |    
+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

What function could I use to fix the geometry of this polygon layer and how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, doing a self-union or self-intersection corrects those kinds of errors: call the `SDO_GEOM.SDO_UNION(GEOMETRY,GEOMETRY,0.05)` to update the shape (assuming that your tolerance is really 0.05).

BUT: this may actually just hide the error. The error code is returned when a polygon boundary crosses itself, i.e. it was incorrectly digitized. The above operation just hides the error (= the polygon is no longer diagnosed as incorrect) but it does not alter the visual shape.

So I advise to visually look at those two shapes and see what the actual error is.

The error may also be thrown if the polygon just touches itself = its boundary doubles back and touches itself somewhere else - like for example a crescent shape where the two extremities touch each other. That kind of shape can be safely corrected using the above method: it will be turned into a polygon with hole where the hole touches the outer ring.

You may also want to look at the SDO_UTIL.RECTIFY_GEOMETRY() function. It attempts to correct the three most common geometric errors:

- Duplicate points
- Incorrect orientation (polygons)
- self touching/self crossing polygons